tRest component giving different output
In talend I am using tRest component to make an API call. When i browse the API Url I am getting the desired json output it should be giving.But in the job, when I call the API I am getting an HTML output in the body column. Please help
I tried using context variables and using the api url in the patb as well but the same html output is generated in body column

can you what you tried, the configuration of the component, ...

Update the quesyion to show the tRest Basic settings and the content of context variable used,

You probably need to add the Accept HTTP header to specify that you want a JSON response ( application/json ).


tried this, not getting result
